# NumericQ and unknown number of variable in a module-block

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, numerical-value

I have the following problem I want to address in an elegant way. I have a function of many variables `f[x, y, z,...]` I want to find the minimum with `NMinimize`. My function is itself an external module like:

```
f[x_, y_, z_, ...] := Module[{},
    many operations,
    Return[Number]]
```

Given that, the `NMinimize` should work as follows `NMinimize[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]` for instance. To make it work, I have to add to each variable of my function `f` the following.

```
f[x_NumericQ, y_NumericQ, z_NumericQ, ...]
```

However, if I do not know in advance my number of variables, I do not see any way of making `f[x_NumericQ, y_NumericQ, z_NumericQ, ...]` generic for an $n$ number of variables.

Would any of you have any idea about how to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pattern test sequences of arguments like this using `__?`:

```
g[x__?NumericQ] := 4*Total[{x}] + {x}[[1]]
g[1,2,3] (* returns 4*(1+2+3 + 1) which is 25 *)
g[1,2,y] (* returns g[1,2,y] *)
```

... or like this if you pass in a list:

```
f[x_?(ListQ[#] && And @@ (NumericQ /@ #) &)] := x[[1]] + x[[2]] + x[[3]]
f[{1,2,3}] (* returns 6 *)
f[{1,2,"hello"}] (* returns f[{1,2,hello}] *)
```

... but this looks better for lists, courtesy of **@Michael E2**:

```
f[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := x[[1]] + x[[2]] + x[[3]]
```

Here's an example minimization in action where you can add more variables:

```
f[v__?NumericQ] := Total[{v}] + 2*Last[{v}] + 4*{v}[[1]]^2
variables = {x, y, z, w}
NMinimize[{f @@ variables,
  Last[variables] > 3,
  Abs[variables[[1]] + variables[[2]]] > 4,
  0 < # < 20 & /@ variables},
 Evaluate[variables]
]
```

Comment: I'd code `f` as `f[v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=...` (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks - I didn't know that one.

Comment: That is a beautiful and elegant answer f[v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)]. It worked very well! Thanks a lot!